# Nested NIntegrate with variable limits

Tags: numerical-integration

Im trying to integrate the following:

\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{x} J_{3/4}(x^2 z)J_{1/4}(y^2z) dy dz dx
\end{equation}

So what I did was this

```
i1[x_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 i1[x, z] = NIntegrate[BesselJ[1/4, y^2 z], {y, -1, x}]
i2[x_?NumericQ] := 
 i2[x] = NIntegrate[BesselJ[3/4, x^2 z] i1[x, z], {z, -1, 1}]
NIntegrate[i2[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Is this correct? And if so, is there any other way to make this faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it as a multiple integral?  How precise do you want the answer?

Comment: I haven't tried it. However, my post is just something that looks similar to my original problem and my original problem is something that needs numerical integration. I just want a result that does not show this: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the \
following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly \
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the integral is `0` exactly, by symmetry (`z -> -z`):

```
FullSimplify[
 BesselJ[3/4, x^2 z] BesselJ[1/4, y^2 z] + 
   BesselJ[3/4, x^2 (-z)] BesselJ[1/4, y^2 (-z)],
 {x, y, z} ∈ Reals]
(*  0  *)
```

Numerical test: Set it up so that the ["EvenOddSubdivision"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#172715735) strategy may be applied to the `z`-integral:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[3/4, x^2 z] BesselJ[1/4, y^2 z],
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, x}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Method -> {"EvenOddSubdivision", 
   Method -> {"LobattoKronrodRule", "GaussPoints" -> 5}}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, AccuracyGoal -> 16]
(*  1.9636*10^-18  *)
```

(You need to set a finite `AccuracyGoal` to avoid a convergence warning.)

Comment: Thanks. But is the code right?

Comment: @PhilCsar Do you mean did *Mathematica* make a mistake? Or are you suggesting I messed up the cut & paste of the integrand?  -- The interval `-1 <= z <= 1` is symmetric with respect to the reflection `z -> -z`, so the integral over `{z, -1, 0}` cancels the integral over `{z, 0, 1}`....if there's no error in my copying.  It agrees with numerical tests, up to the error in numerical integration which is somewhat large (<0.001).

Comment: Im just asking if my code is correct because Im not sure if I used NumericQ correctly :D

Comment: @PhilCsar It seems right, but it will be slow.

Comment: @PhilCsar If an integral is zero, `NIntegrate` will always give a convergence warning unless you set a finite `AccuracyGoal` to however many digits you want verified are zero.